# Construction of an isomorphism $T|_U$ from a surjective linear map $T\in\mathcal{L}(V,W)$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

Is the Following Proof Correct ?

**Theorem.** Given that $V$ is *finite-dimensional* and $T\in\mathcal{L}(V,W)$ such that $T$ is *surjective*, then there exists a $U\leqslant V$ such that $T|_U$ (here $T|_U$ is the map $T$ with domain restricted to $U$) is an *isomorphism* from $U$ onto $W$.

**Proof.** Since $T$ is surjective we know that $\forall w\in W\exists v\in V(Tv=w)$ therefore we may define a function $\phi:W\to \mathcal{P}(V)$ such that 
$\phi(w)=\{v\in V\ |\ Tv=w\}\neq \varnothing$ now let $$U = \bigcup_{w\in W}S_{\phi(w)}$$ where 
$S_{\phi(w)}$ is an arbitrary subset of $\phi(w)$ such that $|S_{\phi(w)}|=1$.

Is is evident that $U\leqslant V$ since $T\in\mathcal{L}(V,W)$ moreover the *surjectivity* of $T|_U$ is also evident since $\forall w\in W(|S_{\phi(w)|}=1)$, now to establish *injectivity* assume that $T|_Uv_1=T|_Uv_2=w$ where $v_1$ and $v_2$ are arbitrary vectors in $V$ we know that for $w$ there exists a $S_{\phi(w)}$ such that $|S_{\phi(w)}|=1$ which implies that $v_1=v_2$ implying that $T|_U$ is *injective* consequently we may deduce that $T|_U$ is an *isomorphism* from $U$ onto $W$.

$\blacksquare$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the subsets $S_{\phi(w)}$ are chosen arbitrarily, then there is no reason for $U$ to be a subspace of $V$. For instance, if $V=\mathbb{R}^2$, $W=\mathbb{R}$, and $T$ is the projection $(x,y)\mapsto x$, then we could choose $S_{\phi(0)}=(0,1)$ and $U$ won't be a subspace because it won't contain $(0,0)$.

Instead, I suggest choosing a basis $\{w_1,\dots,w_n\}$ for $W$, then choosing vectors $v_j$ such that $Tv_j=w_j$, then taking $U=\mathrm{span}\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$.

Comment: I thought about the approach you suggested in the second paragraph but we dont know whether $W$ is finite dimensional so how can we choose a basis for $W$?

Comment: and will the above proof be correct if i ensure that $S_{\phi(0)}=\{0\}$ ?

Comment: Since $T$ is surjective, the dimension of $W$ is at most that of $V$. And no, my example with $S_{\phi(0)}$ is just one way that this construction can go wrong.

Comment: Just some clarification on your first comment what your saying is that the surjectivity of $T$ implies that $\dim W \leq \dim V$

Comment: Yes. Indeed, if $\{v_1,\dots,v_m\}$ is a basis for $V$ then $\{Tv_1,\dots,Tv_m\}$ spans $W$, so $\dim W\leq m$.